# Show active threads JMeter without waittimes

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test with 100 concurrent users. In this test I have built in random waittimes. How can I see how many users are active (not by a wait time) by time? I'm installing the JMeter plugins and tried the [Active Threads over time listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) but it doesn't show the wait times. Is there another listener what I can use? Or can I create a log?
[image]

In this graph you see a run with one thread. In this run i have build in some waittimes. In the graph i dont see that the active threads going to 0 if there is an waittime. The active threads are the whole run 1.

Comment: So you want graph to show the wait time period when there were no or less active users ? I believe this graph should do the required job if  configured properly. Can you share more details of your plan/environment? Are you running tests from command line? distributed mode?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i add more explanation.